# Understanding part of the proof for Coupon Collector's Problem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, independence

The following claim appeared in the proof of the Coupon Collector's Problem and I am not sure why the last sentence is true:

> Fix uniform i.i.d. random variables $X_{i, n}$ taking values in $\{ 1, \cdots, n \}$. Fix also $T_{n, 0} = 0$ and $T_{n, k} := \min\{ m \geq 1: |\bigcup_{i = 1} ^m \{ X_{i,n} \}| = k \}$. It is desired to show $\{ T_{n, k} - T_{n, k - 1} \}_{k = 1} ^n$ are mutually independent. It is enough to show that $T_{n, k} - T_{n, k - 1}$ is independent from the vector $Y := (T_{n, 1} - T_{n, 0}, T_{n, 2} - T_{n, 1}, \cdots, T_{n, k - 1} - T_{n, k - 2})$. Furthermore, **it is sufficient to check that $T_{n, k} - T_{n, k - 1}$ is independent from $\sigma$-field $\sigma(T_{n, 1}, T_{n, 2}, \cdots, T_{n, k - 1})$**.

My question about the last sentence: Why is it sufficient to show $T_{n, k} - T_{n, k - 1}$ is independent from $\sigma(T_{n, 1}, T_{n, 2},  \cdots, T_{n, k - 1})$ instead of $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: It says independent from vector $Y,$ not from $\sigma(Y).$ I don't myself know what $\sigma(Y)$ means, since $Y$ has been defined as just a vector of variables.

Comment: @coffeemath $\sigma(Y)$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the preimage of Borel sets under $Y$.

Comment: By "under $Y$" do you mean some set generated by the components of the vector $Y$? [To me a $\sigma$ algebra is usually generated by a collection of sets]

Comment: $Y$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{k - 1}$, so $\sigma(Y) = \{ Y^{-1}(S): S \in \mathrm{Bor}(\mathbb{R}^{k - 1}) \}$.